# What is the correct return method type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gamesparks

I have a method that uses Gamespark Api to get leaderboard data.

I want to return that data to another class to look over and update a Unity prefab.

From my leaderboard class I can loop the data fine, but I am confused what return type I need to use the same loop code from another class

```
public class LeaderboardManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public GSEnumerable<LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData> LeaderboardRequest (string leaderboard, int entryCount = 50, bool social = false)
{
    GSEnumerable<LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData> data = null;

    new LeaderboardDataRequest()
        .SetLeaderboardShortCode(leaderboard)
        .SetEntryCount(entryCount)
        .SetSocial(social)
        .Send((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors)
            {
                Debug.Log("Found Leaderboard Data...");
                foreach (LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData entry in response.Data)
                {
                    int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
                    string playerName = entry.UserName;
                    string score = entry.JSONData["SCORE"].ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
                }
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Error Retrieving Leaderboard Data...");
                return;
            }
    });

    return data;
}

}

public class StartController : MonoBehaviour {

#region Variables

public string leaderboardName;

private GSEnumerable<LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData> leaderboardResults;

    void Start () {
        leaderboardResults = NetworkManager.Instance.leaderboard.LeaderboardRequest(leaderboardName, 10, true);

        foreach (LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData entry in leaderboardResults.Data)
        {
            int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
            string playerName = entry.UserName;
            string score = entry.JSONData["SCORE"].ToString();
            Debug.Log("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
        }

    }
```

I get the error that `leaderboardResults.Data` in the foreach in the `StartController` class `GSEnumerable does not contain a definition for Data and no accessible extension.

The `foreach` in the `LeaderboardManager` prints ok

I have tried to return the `response.Data` as `ArrayList` and I get an error on the `return data;` `Anonymous function converted to void returning delegate cannot return value`

```
public ArrayList LeaderboardRequest (string leaderboard, int entryCount = 50, bool social = false)
{
    //GSEnumerable<LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData> data = null;

    new LeaderboardDataRequest()
        .SetLeaderboardShortCode(leaderboard)
        .SetEntryCount(entryCount)
        .SetSocial(social)
        .Send((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors)
            {
                Debug.Log("Found Leaderboard Data...");
                foreach (LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData entry in response.Data)
                {
                    int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
                    string playerName = entry.UserName;
                    string score = entry.JSONData["SCORE"].ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
                }
                GSEnumerable<LeaderboardDataResponse._LeaderboardData> data = response.Data;
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Error Retrieving Leaderboard Data...");
                return;
            }
    });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Seems like response has Data
as shown in docs
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5RH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5RH.png)

Comment: In the context of the LeaderboardManager class `response.Data` works fine. However my difficulty is trying to return that response to another class. I no longer have access to the `.Data`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is another solution for this then. You can create static action:

```
public static Action<LeaderboardDataResponse> GetResponce;
```

Then in LeaderboardDataRequest invoke this action

```
new LeaderboardDataRequest()
    .SetLeaderboardShortCode(leaderboard)
    .SetEntryCount(entryCount)
    .SetSocial(social)
    .Send((response) => {
        GetResponce?.Invoke(response);
        //Do something if you need here
});
```

In your script on start subscribe to action

```
void Start()
{
     LeaderboardManager.GetResponce += GotData;
}
```

And GotData func:

```
public void GotData(LeaderboardDataResponse response)
{
    if (!response.HasErrors)
    {
        foreach (var entry in response.Data)
        {
            int rank = (int)entry.Rank;
            string playerName = entry.UserName;
            string score = entry.JSONData["SCORE"].ToString();
            Debug.Log("Rank:" + rank + " Name:" + playerName + " \n Score:" + score);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError(response.JSONData);
    }
}
```

So, you just have to call in your leaderboard manager request to get data and another class would get response

Just checked it works fine

Comment: Thank you for that. I want to be able to call the leaderboard method from the other class too. Would you recommend putting the `LeaderboardItemController controller = newLeaderboard.GetComponent<LeaderboardItemController>();` under the `LeaderboardManager.GetResponce += GotData;` in the Start?

Comment: You can make method static or add singleton to your class. And get its instance to call wanted method

Comment: did you resolve your problem? mark question answered pls :)